Issue with Data Preprocessing and Tensor Concatenation for Whisper Model Training
I am trying to train a Whisper model for Jeju dialect speech recognition. However, I am encountering several errors related to tensor concatenation during the data preprocessing phase. Below is the detailed description of my code, the errors I am facing, and the solutions I have attempted.
Environment

Google Colab

Python 3.10

Using Transformers, Datasets, and Librosa libraries


Data Structure

A directory jss/ containing multiple WAV files (0.wav, 1.wav, ...)

A jss.v.1.0.tsv file containing the audio file paths, transcripts, text length, and audio length information


Code

Environment Setup and Kaggle API Key Configuration
!pip install kaggle
!pip install transformers datasets librosa

from google.colab import files
files.upload()  # Upload kaggle.json file

!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!mv kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!kaggle datasets download -d bryanpark/jejueo-single-speaker-speech-dataset
!unzip jejueo-single-speaker-speech-dataset.zip


Loading and Preprocessing Data


import os
import pandas as pd
from datasets import Dataset, Audio

# Set dataset paths
audio_dir = "jss"
transcript_file = "jss.v.1.0.tsv"

# Load transcripts (TSV file)
df = pd.read_csv(transcript_file, sep='\t', header=None, names=['path', 'transcript', 'text_length', 'audio_length'])
df['path'] = df['path'].apply(lambda x: os.path.join(audio_dir, x))
df = df.head(5000)

# Prepare dataset
data = {
    "audio": df['path'].tolist(),
    "transcript": df['transcript'].tolist()
}

dataset = Dataset.from_dict(data)
dataset = dataset.cast_column("audio", Audio(sampling_rate=16000))

print(dataset)


Data Preprocessing and Tokenization
from transformers import WhisperProcessor, WhisperFeatureExtractor, WhisperTokenizer
import torch
import librosa

# Load Whisper model processor
feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-small")
tokenizer = WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-small")
processor = WhisperProcessor(feature_extractor, tokenizer)

# Data preprocessing
def preprocess_data(dataset):
    inputs = []
    for example in dataset:
        audio = example["audio"]["array"]
        sampling_rate = example["audio"]["sampling_rate"]
        transcript = example["transcript"]

        input_features = feature_extractor(audio, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, return_tensors="pt")
        labels = tokenizer(transcript, return_tensors="pt", padding="longest")
        inputs.append({
            "input_features": input_features.input_features.squeeze(0),
            "labels": labels.input_ids.squeeze(0)
        })
    return inputs

processed_data = preprocess_data(dataset)
print(f"Processed data count: {len(processed_data)}")



Converting to Dataset


from datasets import Dataset

# Convert processed data to Dataset
def collate_fn(batch):
    input_features = torch.stack([item["input_features"] for item in batch])
    labels = torch.stack([item["labels"] for item in batch])
    return {"input_features": input_features, "labels": labels}

processed_dataset = Dataset.from_dict({
    "input_features": [data["input_features"].numpy() for data in processed_data],
    "labels": [data["labels"].numpy() for data in processed_data],
})

print(processed_dataset)


Model Training Setup and Training

from transformers import WhisperForConditionalGeneration, TrainingArguments, Trainer

# Load Whisper model
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-small")

# Training setup
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    eval_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
)

# Define Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=processed_dataset,
    eval_dataset=processed_dataset,
    data_collator=collate_fn,
)

# Train model
trainer.train()

Issues
While running the above code, I encountered the following errors:

Tensor Concatenation Error

TypeError: expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got list


Batch Data Preprocessing Error

IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3

Attempted Solutions

Using padding=True, padding="longest" options

Changing torch.cat to torch.stack

Adjusting dimensions and conversion of input_features and labels


Request for Assistance
I would appreciate any guidance on the correct data preprocessing and tensor transformation methods to resolve these issues. My goal is to properly preprocess and train the Whisper model to recognize Jeju dialect speech.
Thank you!
